# How to make Hamburger Icon menu function to work with single click in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, navbar, hamburger-menu, react-state

I have been following a coding tutorial of making responsive Navbar from Youtube in Html,CSS and JS.
 While i really wanted to remake it again in react, the hamburger icon works flawlessly previously when i made it in plain Html, CSS and JS [Click here to see the example](http://static-cfmnavbar.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/). (Switch the browser in mobile view to see the Hamburger icon)

But when I copied all my code in react (as follows):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style/navbar.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const navslide = () => {
      const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
      const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
      burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");

        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
          if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = "";
          } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
              0.5}s`;
          }
        });

        burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <nav>
          <div className="logo">
            <h3>College Facemash</h3>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav-links">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">Login / Signup</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="burger" onClickCapture={navslide}>
            <div className="line1"></div>
            <div className="line2"></div>
            <div className="line3"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default navbar;
```

it worked well but not not functioning in single click. Instead it did required Double click to function.

[Click here to see the demo](http://navbar-collfm.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/).(Switch the browser in mobile view to see the Hamburger icon)

So, What changes should i made in order to make my code work flawlessly

Your help would be really valuable to me. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why calling `burger.addEventListener("click")` while your function will run on burger click! this is why it need 2 click to run!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./style/navbar.css";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class navbar extends Component {
      render() {
        const navslide = () => {
          const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
          const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
          const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
            nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");

            navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
              if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = "";
              } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
                  0.5}s`;
              }
            });

            burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
        };

        return (
          <div>
            <nav>
              <div className="logo">
                <h3>College Facemash</h3>
              </div>
              <ul className="nav-links">
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/login">Login / Signup</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div className="burger" onClick={navslide}>
                <div className="line1"></div>
                <div className="line2"></div>
                <div className="line3"></div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default navbar;
```

also i recommend adding state to your component and changing it when ham is clicked!
and then you can change elements classes depending on this state.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    const navslide = () => {
      const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
      nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
      navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
          if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = "";
          } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
          }
        });

        burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
      });
    };
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <nav>
          <div className="logo">
            <h3>College Facemash</h3>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav-links">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/login">Login / Signup</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="burger" onClick={() => navslide()}>
            <div className="line1"></div>
            <div className="line2"></div>
            <div className="line3"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```